# "EPIC requires a Perl interpreter" in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, windows, perl, epic

I have installed Eclipse Kepler and EPIC, the Java Development Kit, and ActivePerl.

When I create a Perl script and try to run it as Perl local I get the error

```
To operate correctly, EPIC requires a Perl interpreter
```

I don't understand why that is. Am I going wrong because I have installed Active Perl? Why is it that my Perl interpreter is not detected by EPIC?

I installed EPIC from [the betas here](http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/). I went to `Help/Install new software/Add` then I entered this link and followed the instructions. Then my Eclipse also restarted

I am still unable to run a Perl script because of the above error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the Perl executable's *absolute path* in EPIC configuration under Eclipse. Here are are the steps

```
Eclipse -> Window (on menu) -> Preferences -> PerlEPIC -> Perl Executable (on hte right hand side pane) -> /usr/bin/perl (this is my perl binary on ubuntu Linux)
```

The `/usr/bin/perl` part is important; that's my Perl executable.

**Note:** The above steps were taken from my Eclipse running on Linux, but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `perl` interpreter in your PATH environment (ie when you issue a `perl` command from the cmd prompt, it will be found)