# how can I import existing perl project in java by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, perl

I have a project which is developed in Perl, Is there any way to run it in Eclipse env?
I use Win8 with Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Service Release 2.

My project contains these files in it:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured eclipse for Perl, then following steps will be helpful.

In file menu, there is an option Import.Go there and from the opened dialog box, choose, Perl project.
After selecting, you will get a dialog box where you need to select the project folder from the local directory structure and the folder where you want to import the project.

Comment: How can I configure Eclipse? Is it possible by EPIC installation?

Comment: In Help->Install Software, go to the official site of the eclipse version you are using, and check for Perl bundles.If available, install them and rest of the work will be done by the eclipse implicitly.

Comment: Thanks alot, I download and install EPIC, I opened the project,but I dont know how can I run it?:(

Comment: click on the green icon present on the toolbar having white arrow. It will automatically select the Run type, whether it is console or web-application.

Comment: Ok, but i get the error:“To operate correctly, EPIC requires a Perl interpreter  check your configuration setting window/prefrences/perlEpic”

Comment: http://www.epic-ide.org/faq.php go to this link and check your eclipse environment with the preferred requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650728/when-i-try-to-run-a-pl-file-in-eclpse-kepler-i-get-the-errorto-operate-correc follow this link.

Comment: Thanks, I think I haven't installed active perl!:P

Comment: If my answer helped you then, support it by clicking on tick button.